# why salesforce provide new map if old map already exist

Tags: apex, trigger

trying to  figure out why new map provided by salesforce if old map already exist.
every one providing difference is there but i am unable to find exact answer,

**newMap    A map of IDs to the new versions of the sObject records.
Note that this map is only available in before update, after insert, and after update triggers.**

**oldMap    A map of IDs to the old versions of the sObject records.
Note that this map is only available in update and delete triggers.**

suggest please.

Answer (score 1):

In `trigger.Oldmap` you get the old values while in `trigger.newmap` you get the new updated values.

Both of there return type is Map. With the help of list we can compare them.

Normally we use trigger.New and `Trigger.oldMap` to compare old and new value without need of nested loops.

```
for(Account acc: trigger.new)
  if(acc.active__c && trigger.oldmap.get(acc.Id).active__c  != acc.active__c)
      //comparing active status and also checking status is changed in update of this record
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an usecase that i have come across. I need to update `Qualified__c` checkbox on lead if `Status` changed to "Qualified". I need to update only when lead status is not "Qualified" before updating. In such situation we can take advantage of `Trigger.newMap`, `Trigger.oldMap`, `Trigger.new`, `Trigger.old`

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before update) {   
    for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {
        // Get the "old" using its ID in Trigger.oldMap
        Lead oldLead = Trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id);

        // Check that Status field not equal "Qalified" before and now changed to "Qualified" then only do update else display error
        if (!oldLead.Status.equals('Qualified') && l.Status.equals('Qualified')) {
           l.Qualified__c = true;
        }
        else{
           l.adderror('Lead status is not changed.');
        }
    }
}
```